# Ponto "de" situação ou Ponto "da" situação?

Tags: expressões, semântica, uso-mais-comum, norma

Em que situações deva usar «Ponto **de** situação» em detrimento de «Ponto **da** situação»?

Comment: sou brasileiro e moro em Lisboa há 1 ano. Trabalho com TI e foi estranho o meu primeiro PDS, que descobri que era o Ponto de Situação (uma reunião de Status). Ouço sempre aqui em Portugal: Ponto de Situação.

Comment: @Peixoto que expressão utilizam em PT-BR para este tipo de situações?

Comment: Acho que usamos o termo em inglês mesmo, Status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta pergunta assume que ambos os casos são possíveis, o que é verdade.

Segundo [Carlos Marinheiro](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ponto-da-situacao/22265)

> Regra geral, a expressão utiliza-se perante uma situação concreta, e,
>   assim, diz-se «ponto **da** situação». Por exemplo, quando há uma greve, o
>   governo faz o "seu" ponto **da** situação e afirma: «a adesão à greve não
>   passou dos 20%»; por sua vez, o respectivo sindicato também faz o
>   "seu" ponto **de** situação e proclama: «a adesão à greve ultrapassou os
>   80%». Com efeito, os «pontos **de** situação» (em geral) como este
>   baseiam-se normalmente em números fantasiosos.

Comment: Nunca ouvi essa expressão em pt-BR

Comment: @Centaurus em pt-PT é bastante usada em âmbito profissional.